# set array's elements as independent variables

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment

I'm looking for a php function that would set array's elements as independent variables (by the same name)

I wrote the code below that should do the trick... 
Is there any function that does that already, in php ?

```
$data = array(...);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
 ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Why do you want to do this as opposed to using the array directly?

Comment: I'm passing multiple variables in array as a parameter, in order to embed them in a view template, but I want the template compatible with planting variables using a javascript library https://github.com/GuyLou/branches.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for PHP extract():

```
extract($data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;

echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";
```

Or

```
foreach($ARRAY as $key=>$value) { 
    $$key = $value; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your 1st script assumes I know what the elements are, your 2nd is what I arrived to by myself